# Select distinct on result

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a stored procedure and it has this case:

```
CASE
WHEN ED.DESCRIPCION IS NOT NULL THEN ED.DESCRIPCION
WHEN  adjuntos > 0 THEN 'PRES' 
WHEN adjuntos=0 AND obligatory = 'N' THEN 'NO'
ELSE 'PEN'
END AS STATE
```

I need to select distinct values of that result `STATE`, something like placing the `DISTINCT` before the case, this stored procedure currently returns:

```
PRES
NO
PEN
PEN
PEN
PEN
```

Comment: You mean put `DISTINCT` before the `CASE`?

Comment: yes alex, thats what im looking for

Comment: Why have you added "some like placing the DISTINT before the case", when that is literally what you should do - `SELECT DISTINCT CASE WHEN ... END AS STATE FROM ...`? What problem do you have doing that?

Comment: [Error] Syntax check (32:15) Found WHEN expecting fo -or- bulk into -or- ,

Comment: You can [see that this works](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=943b235762f718289b6b5850344536b6). Either your client is doing some pre-processing (since that isn't an Oracle error code) or you're doing something different.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the code for the stored procedure where you are using the `CASE` expression. It appears you are probably trying to use this outside of a `SELECT` statement; in which case it is syntactically invalid to add `DISTINCT` before it but we can't answer as to what would work if you don't give us the relevant context.

Answer (score 1):

You literally just need to add the `DISTINCT` keyword:

```
SELECT DISTINCT CASE
WHEN ED.DESCRIPCION IS NOT NULL THEN ED.DESCRIPCION
WHEN  adjuntos > 0 THEN 'PRES' 
WHEN adjuntos=0 AND obligatory = 'N' THEN 'NO'
ELSE 'PEN'
END AS STATE
FROM ...
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=943b235762f718289b6b5850344536b6) with some made-up data.

If you are selecting other columns at the same time then you need `DISTINCT` before the first column expression in the select list. It applies to the entire row of the result set, not to individual columns; and it isn't a function. [From the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/SELECT.html):

> Specify DISTINCT or UNIQUE if you want the database to return only one copy of each set of duplicate rows selected. These two keywords are synonymous. Duplicate rows are those with matching values for each expression in the select list.

But you have only shown one column expression, so this doesn't seem to apply.